# Batch to move file into sub directories excluding parent directory

Tags: batch, file-transfer, xcopy

I have a *otf file that I would like to copy into all the sub directories of the parent folder. This is what I have attempted.

`for /R %%x in (.) do copy "file.otf" "%%x"`

This works for the most part but it also leaves a copy into the parent folder. I would like a fix for this such the the batch only copies into all the sub directories.

Answer (score 0):

I could not get your code to work on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17134.648].  The following code works.

test:

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%x in ('dir /b /s /ad "path-to-parent-folder-with-double-quotes-if-there-is-a-space-in-the-path\"') do echo copy /y "file.otf" to "%%x\"
```

copy:

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%x in ('dir /b /s /ad "path-to-parent-folder-with-double-quotes-if-there-is-a-space-in-the-path\"') do copy /y "file.otf" "%%x\"
```

delete file.otf from subdirectories:

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%x in ('dir /b /s /ad "path-to-parent-folder-with-double-quotes-if-there-is-a-space-in-the-path\"') do del /q "%%x\file.otf"
```

tokens=* takes care of spaces in the path/filename

```
"tokens=*"
```

**dir /b /s /ad copies the file to a directory and not to a file. Without /ad file.otr will overwrite all files in the directory.** Use copy instead of copy /y if you are worried.

```
dir /b /s /ad
```

copy /y overwrites file.otr without asking for permission. You are bound to try a couple of times before you are satisfied it is working.

```
copy /y
```

Instead of "fixing" your code why don't you just delete file.otr in the parent directory?

```
del /q file.otr
```

Comment: Welcome to Super User! This answer would be improved by adding an explanation of these commands and how they're different from the command the OP tried.